# Can I time out my scripted "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;"?

Tags: mysql, backup, snapshot

I have a single Enterprise Linux 6 system running MySQL 5.5. I am attempting to use [LVM to capture a weekly filesystem snapshot](http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/mysql-backups-using-lvm-snapshots).

However, as many of us have experienced, "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;" can lead to a [deadlock situation, create a backlog of queries](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/04/24/how-fast-is-flush-tables-with-read-lock/), fill up the connection pool and effectively knock the system offline. In fact last night my "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;" didn't complete until 8 hours after execution due to a long running query.

If I perform the MySQL snapshot using a script like this, can I somehow time out the "FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;". If it doesn't execute after a period of time I would like to kill it and avoid the inevitable deadlock.

```
mysql -u root <<-MYSQL_INPUT
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
SYSTEM /usr/local/bin/mysql-create-lvm-snapshot;
UNLOCK TABLES;
\q
MYSQL_INPUT
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reliable way of interrupting `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`. I disagree with the previous answer. You can try KILLing the `FLUSH` query all you want. Typically this will just hang till the original command completes.

However, some good news for you. You should be aware that `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` is not strictly necessary in order to take LVM snapshot.

It is *required* if:

- You are interested in point in time recovery (applying incremental restore via binlogs)
- You have lots of non-transactional (ie MyISAM) tables being written to
- You are running the snapshot against the master and want to create a slave based on the snapshot.

If your database is InnoDB oriented, and nothing interesting is hapenning with your MyISAM system tables (ie no one creating a procedure, GRANTing privileges etc.) then it's enough that you `FLUSH` only those tables.

All things InnoDB, you can just take the snapshot. There is no benefit in `FLUSH`ing. InnoDB will make proper recovery anyhow.

The need for `FLUSH TABLE` comes from the requirement of getting the binary log file and position when you want to be able to rebuild a slave or otherwise use binary logs.

Comment: Thanks Shiomi. This database hosts a hodge-podge of MyISAM and InnoDB tables, so I believe I need to stay with the `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`.

Answer (score 3):

Mysql 5.6 introduced `FLUSH TABLES FOR EXPORT` which might be a better option for your use case if you use InnoDB exclusively (apart from the internal mysql database which is always MyISAM):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flush.html

Unfortunately I cannot comment here (yet), but I did quite some research on the answer of Shlomi Noach above. I hope he is right, but I could not find a confirmation of his statement that taking a filesystem snapshot of InnoDB tables does never lead to data corruption.

From the comments of https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html:

> For a filesystem snapshot of innodb, we find that setting
>   innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct to zero; doing a 'flush tables with
>   readlock'; and then waiting for the innodb state to reach 'Main thread
>   process no. \d+, id \d+, state: waiting for server activity' is
>   sufficient to quiesce innodb.

From http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/23/how-flush-tables-with-read-lock-works-with-innodb-tables/:

> If you’re just using Innodb tables and you’re not actively changing
>   users, stored procedures etc (which are stored in MyISAM tables
>   anyway) you can consider using –no-lock option with Percona
>   Xtrabackup.

Which would imply that a flush/lock is not necessary if you could rule out administrative changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version

Call lock + bash script (`mysql_lock_wait.sql`):

```
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
SYSTEM bash /opt/mysql_wait.sh;
UNLOCK TABLES;
\q
```

Lock script (`mysql_wait.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCK_FILE="/tmp/mysql_lock"

touch ${LOCK_FILE}

while [ -f ${LOCK_FILE} ]; do
    sleep 0.5
done
```

So now to use that, just run `mysql < /tmp/lock_wait.sql &` and next do whatever you need like taking volume snapshot.

When you want to release the lock, `rm -f /tmp/mysql_lock`.

Voila !